# One of the configured repositories failed (centos-7 - media)

Tags: vmware-workstation, centos-7, yum

I just installed centos-7 on VMware. While trying to run the command

> yum update

it gives me an error saying,

> one of the configured repositories failed (centos-7 - media)

I tried all the possible methods but this is not working. Please help me out.

[CLI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecpF1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Here is the solution. First go to media repo using vi editor,

> vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo

Then disable it by doing the following change,

> enabled=0

Now save it and exit. Things should work now.